# Is there any way we can change the format of log files generated for copy activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Currently I am getting .txt format generated log files for copy activity logs, can it be customized to generate .csv log files?

Answer (score 0):

Based on MSFT docs , Log files are CSV files only

[image]